# Truncate float so as to have only two decimals

Tags: c++, floating-point, truncate, rounding, fractions

**C++**

I would like to `cout` `float f = 2.3333`, but only with two decimals. How do I do that?
I remember something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
cout << f:2 << endl;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you remember that from!

Comment: @sftrabbit I'd guess he remembers it from `printf()`, or another programming language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using stream manipulators [`fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
#include <iomanip>

float f = 2.3333;
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << f;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it without iomanip:

```
cout << (((int)f*100) % 100)/100;
```